# Mongoose | manipulate document in pre('save') hook

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Basically, I'm trying to add a property to my document before saving it to the mongo database.

I would like to create a new Customer document in my Database. I'm doing that with a simple `Customer.create(customer)`. But before actually saving it to the database, I would like to add a `customerNumber` property to the document. As the create() method also calls the save() method internally, I am doing that in a pre('save') hook. As the `this` keyword refers to the document in the save hook, I thought I can just manipulate that and that would be all. But this isn't working.

Of course I could easily implement that without the hook by just manipulating the customer object before calling `.create()` but in my opinion, it would feel much cleaner if this gets done in a pre save hook.

Is that even possible in Mongoose?

Comment: can you show me the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just try like this for pre hook save:

```
customerSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
  this.customerNumber = "somethings"
  return next()
});
```

**note**: the `customerNumber` should be is defined in the schema

Comment: OMG! I can see the answer to my own question now! I tried your version and was like.. Wait why is that working? Then I noticed that I don't call next() inside the then() block. Of course this won't work.. :D

Unbeliveable that it took me a couple hours to figure this out. Thank you very much!